# Can someone please explain how this C code is evaluated?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int a = 2, b = 3, c;
  c = (++a == 3) || (b-- == 2);
  printf("%d", a + b + c);
  printf("%d %d %d", a, b, c);
  return 0;
}
```

The output of the above code is a=3, b=3, c=1.

I understand that `a` was incremented using pre-increment and checked if it is equivalent to 3.

How did `b` become 3 even though it has been decremented?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Please read [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/292176/8075540) on the type of questions that are suited for StackOverflow.

Comment: What specifically don't you understand?  What output did you expect and why?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Yes. a was incremented using pre-increment and checked if it is equivalent to 3. I understood that part

Comment: I don't understand how b became 3 eventhough it has been decremented

Comment: Has it? (keyword: short-circuit evaluation for `||`)

Comment: @thunder_trek Because of the short-circuit, the second half of the || is not evaluated.

Comment: In case you find the term "short circuit" confusing when applied to C programming, check out [What is the meaning of "short circuit" operators?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/289828)